# How to intergrate Ambari for my own hadoop cluster without hdp

Tags: hadoop

I have created a hadoop cluster with 3 nodes. I don't use hdp for this cluster. Now I want to integrate with Ambari. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Install+Ambari+1.6.1+from+Public+Repositories

Comment: hi ,thanks for the reply ,i have installed the ambari in centos, it is showing hdp stack selection , but i didnt use hdp for hadoop cluster, i  have directly configure hadoop from tar.

Comment: hi, does hortonworks data platform(hdp) is mandatory for ambari?

Comment: not sure about it.. will let you know.

Comment: are you resolve this problem ? Can you write tutorial  ?

Comment: hi,I have wind up this approach

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop stack available to Ambari is driven by Stacks:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38571133

In addition to HDP, looks like the BigTop folks are also contributing a Stack starting at Ambari 1.7.0:

https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks